# Switching between tabs within the same Window in an app

Tags: macos, application-switcher

I am trying to switch between tabs within the same window in apps running on my MacBook Air.

What keyboard shortcut can I use to perform the switch conveniently?

Comment: For which program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A universal keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> to tab towards left and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> to tab towards right. (You'll need to press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, to enter <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> key).

This shortcut works with almost all the apps that I personally use, which support multiple tabs under a single window. A few examples include: Apple's own apps such as:

- Safari
- Maps
- Preview
- Terminal
- Xcode

as well as 3rd party apps such as:

- Sublime Text
- Google Chrome
- Firefox
- Opera

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is no **Universal** way to do this, unless you're content to do all your work in Safari and Finder (as @iTunes said).

Even terminal has a different scheme for switching (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>).

In Firefox and Chrome, it's <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>.

Comment: @NimeshNeema: Thanks for the edit; I only recently learned of the `<kbd>` tag. It seems to be unique to this SE site. I'm curious if that's documented anywhere; I ordinarily refer to [this page as my guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help), but it's not listed here.

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to go to the left tab and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to go the to right tab.

This works in both Finder and Safari. It could be other combinations for other programs.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> works in a lot of applications, including Safari, Firefox, Finder, and Terminal. It's also cross-platform - works on Windows as well to switch between program tabs. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> reverses order (right-to-left instead of left-to-right).

Comment: Frankly I am surprised that there are SO MANY other ways to do this - I've only ever used the combo above, didn't know the others listed in this thread even existed...

Answer (score 0):

How to use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (or any other shortcut) for switching tabs:

1. Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts.
2. Click on *Google Chrome*, then on plus sign.

[image]

3. In *Menu Title* type "Select next tab" and in *Keyboard Shortcut* record <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> combination.

[image]

Do the same for *Select previous tab* menu title.